# Visual SVN is not working in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022, windows-11, visualsvn

Today, I installed Windows 11 and Visual Studio 2022. The last time, I used Visual SVN for managing my solutions. I want same environment for learning.

[image]

Visual SVN server is installed successfully. And Visual SVN client installed successfully and I can see the this list in the Visual Studio extension dialog.

But in solution explorer and its menu, I can't see anything in relation to SVN.

How can I resolve this problem?

I tried to control security function on OS. But it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you explicitly enable Visual SVN as your tool of choice for Source Control?

[image]

Go there using <kbd>Tools</kbd> -> <kbd>Options</kbd> -> <kbd>Source Control</kbd> or using Feature Search:

[image]

Comment: First I am so sorry to say notthing for a long time. Because I was in hospital. Thank you so much for your help. I gonna try now.

Comment: Dear jessehouwing! Thank you so much your help. I resolved this problem from your hint. I uninstall SVN extension and disable select the none list in the source control dialog. I install Visual SVN again and now everything OK! Thanks to your help again. From Ali Ali